# NullPointerException for my implementation of Cipher

Tags: java, security, encryption, cryptography

I'm trying to implement [Cipher](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/crypto/Cipher.html), using the [protected constructor of that class](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/crypto/Cipher.html#Cipher(javax.crypto.CipherSpi,%20java.security.Provider,%20java.lang.String)):

```
protected Cipher(CipherSpi cipherSpi, Provider provider, String transformation)
```

but it fails with a `NullPointerException` without any message within that constructor. I've supplied all arguments, even my own `CipherSpi`, so why does it throw this exception?

Comment: Out of curiosity - what is this question? And why the answer does not recommend to extend `CipherSpi` and do not touch `Cipher` ever?

Comment: @OlegEstekhin You actually *must* implement `CipherSpi` (even in the question above), but you cannot only use `CipherSpi` if you want to get around using a provider. You would think that extending `Cipher` is a way around the checks, but it isn't; this is what you get if you try; just a `NullPointerException`. I'll try and make this even more clear in the question.

Comment: So the problem is how to use Cipher API without creating provider? And the answer is to create special Cipher subclass, "regular" CipherSpi and then sign this "lightweight" quasi-provider?

Comment: @OlegEstekhin No, if you can create a signed provider, you should just create a CipherSpi and a Service within the provider (I have created providers before). Thanks for your questions, I'll try and update this evening when I get back from work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is a security check that is performed in that same constructor. Instead of throwing  more precise exception it just throws the runtime exception:

```
if (!JceSecurityManager.INSTANCE.isCallerTrusted()) {
    throw new NullPointerException();
}
```

The code was taken from the [GPL'ed source code of OpenJDK 7](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/7-b147/javax/crypto/Cipher.java) starting at line 250. It should be the same for any Oracle version of Java SE.

This is part of the requirement that a security provider needs to be signed before it can be used. To sign the provider you need to create code signing key pair and a certificate obtained from Oracle. To understand how to obtain one, please take a look at the [technote: "How to Implement a Provider in the Java Cryptography Architecture"](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/security/crypto/HowToImplAProvider.html).

Note that many other classes *can* be extended, but they still cannot be part of a `Provider` in the list of trusted providers within the `Security` class (i.e. calling `Signature.getInstance(String algorithm)` will never return your implementation.

Note that this restriction may not be present in other (unofficial) Java implementations.